# Reducing the size of JSON to dataframe - Is there an equivalent 'usecols' argument for pandas.read_json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, amazon-s3, bigdata

I'm trying to reduce the size of a dataframe I have.

The source data is gzipped JSON and approx. 20 GB in s3 and each line looks like this:

`{"timestamp":"1633121635","name":"www.hello.com","type":"a","value":"ipv4:1.1.1.1"}`

I'm using `pandas.read_json` to read it in chunks and then drop the keys I don't want, e.g.

```
for df in pd.read_json(s3_source_data_location,
                           lines=True,
                           chunksize=20000000):
    df.drop('timestamp', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop('type', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I know I can try reducing the size by fiddling around with the datatypes for 'value' and 'name' but I want to first see if I can only read the keys I want.

pandas.read_csv has a 'usecols' argument where you can specify the columns you want to read. Hoping there is a way I can do this with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Lookig at the structure of JSON, you only want to keep name and value. So in order to do that and reduce the computing type, first create a list of columns you want to keep in the dataframe:

```
cols = ['name', 'value']
```

Then create an empty list and define your file path:

```
data = []
file_name = 'path-of-json-file.json'
```

Then open and read for specific categories:

```
with open(file_name, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        doc = json.loads(line)
        lst = [doc['name'], doc['value']]
        data.append(lst)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
```